# Batch downloading files with the date in the file name

Tags: bash, scripts

I would like to write a Linux script to download picture from a web site, with different date. I suppose I need three loops for the YY, MM and DD. YY should be 1974–2017, MM 01–12 and DD 01–31. How does it look like in a small Linux bash script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume one of your files is  `https://www.url.com/2017-11-16.png` and only the date changes. You **could** use [Bash Brace Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) to compute the dates and download the files in one run:

```
wget https://www.url.com/{2016..2017}-{01..02}-{01..02}.png
```

However, this will not work for *very* many URLs like in your case because there's a limit to the length of a terminal command. An alternative is a `for` loop:

```
for i in {2016..2017}-{01..02}-{01..02}; do
  wget https://www.url.com/$i.png
done
```

But you'll still get dates like 2017-02-31 with this approach. To only get *actual* dates we need `date` like in this script taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37220739/6164712):

```
#!/bin/bash
startdate=2017-11-14
enddate=2017-11-16
d=
n=0
until [ "$d" = "$enddate" ]; do  
  d=$(date -d "$startdate + $n days" +%Y-%m-%d)
  wget https://www.url.com/$d.png
  ((n++))
done
```

Adjust `startdate` and `enddate` to your exact needs. If you need to change the date format to e.g. `20171116`, do so in both those variables *and* the `date` command, in this example it would be `+%Y%m%d`.